# Form Submit successProperty

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Is there an easy way to tell form.submit() that there's a different successProperty?
Ext never calls success()

Our response looks like this:

```
{
    code: 'success',
    data: {
        foo: bar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When creating a form change `reader` property to new Json reader where you define different `successProperty`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Form', {
   reader: Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Json', {
      successProperty: 'code'
   })
})
```

Comment: Check updated answer. Each form has a standard reader. You just need to customize it a bit.